# Discord.py Blacklist Json Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
  @blacklist.command(aliases=['member'])
  async def user(self,ctx,*,user:typing.Union[discord.Member, discord.User]):
    with open("jsons/blacklistj.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f.read())
    data["blacklisted"].append(user.id)
    print(data)
    with open("jsons/blacklistj.json", "w") as a:
      json.dump(data, a)
    await ctx.send('blacklisted'+ user.id)
```

I am making a blacklisting command using Jsons. It is not working and gives an error `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`.It also erases the Json. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYbDh.png) is what the Json looks like Inside.

Comment: In the JSON, the `blacklisted` key should be in "double quotes", same as if you're declaring it in Python. I don't think this will solve your issue, but it is an issue nonetheless.

Comment: You also have a typo in the decorator: `alises` instead of `aliases`.

Comment: Also you might want to use a proper database, like SQLite, because that will be less susceptible to race conditions, where the file gets overwritten by one piece of code while the other is still running.

Comment: Try printing `data` after loading the JSON and see what shape it has.

Comment: I did all of this, at first it worked and printed `{'blacklisted': [myidthatimnotgonnaputhere]}`, when I did it a second time it gave me the error again. Then when I closed it it erased the Json.

Comment: Are you trying to add just one `user.id` to the JSON or multiple?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why your code doesn't work. This is probably the correct solution:

Your JSON file should look like this:

```
{"blacklisted":[]}
```

And the way you should read it and append a value to it:

```
with open("jsons/blacklistj.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
data["blacklisted"].append("test")
with open("jsons/blacklistj.json", "w") as a:
    json.dump(data, a, indent=4)
```

Comment: I changed the Json files insides to `blacklisted = []` and changed `data`, its still not working with the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: I think I know why your code does not work. I edited the answer. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can't append to the JSON file in that way. We first have to make sure that `"blacklisted"` is already existing.

I made a slightly different code but it works the same way.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@blacklist.command(aliases=['member'])
async def user(self, ctx, *, user: typing.Union[discord.Member, discord.User]):
    with open("jsons/blacklistj.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print("Opened the JSON file.")
    try:
        data[str("Blacklist:")].append(str(user.id))
        await ctx.send("Success, added new ID.")
    except KeyError:
        data[str("Blacklist:")] = [str(user.id)]
        await ctx.send("Blacklist was created as there was no entry.")

    with open("jsons/blacklistj.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

- Be aware that the same ID can be used several times. You must then include a code yourself that checks whether the `user.id` already exists in the JSON.
- To make it a bit simpler you can also define `user.id` as a `str` with `id = str(user.id)` and then insert `id` everywhere.

*A little tip:* You don't have to use `str` and can also just use `user.id` as seen in your example.