# How to use JSON files to black list others using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a blacklist command so that if others abuse my bot I can add their user id and then they get blacklisted. I found code off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719038/discord-py-blacklist-json-command) and I tried to use the code, but the code they use, you have to actually mention the member in order to blacklist them, so now I am stuck.

Here is the code I tried:

```
# black list command attempt one
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner
async def blacklist(ctx, user_id):
    user_id_int = int(user_id)
    guild = ctx.guild
    if user_id_int == None:
        await ctx.send(f"You did not provide an id!")
        print(f"You did not run the blacklist command properly due to providing no id.")
    else:
        with open('blacklist.json', 'r') as blacklist_file:
            users = json.load(blacklist_file)
```

Comment: What's the problem? *I tried to use the code, but the code they use, you have to actually mention the member in order to blacklist them* how else would it work?

Comment: @Daviid ik i want their id to save to a json file so that if my program detects that theyre using the bot in another server it just sends in the channel "You are blacklisted from (name of the bot)!"

Comment: And does the code you posted not do that?

Comment: Wait you're reading the file, open it for writing and add the `user_id_int` to it

Comment: It is what I have done so far, I do not know how I will add the data to the json since idrk how to use json in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing:

```
with open('blacklist.json', 'r') as blacklist_file:
    users = json.load(blacklist_file)
```

Reading the file, load it into `users` and nothing else.

Here's how you read a JSON file and update it to add a user id to it.

```
with open('blacklist.json', 'r+') as blacklist_file:
    users = json.load(blacklist_file)

    users.append(user_id_int)

    blacklist_file.seek(0)
    json.dump(users, blacklist_file, indent=4)
    blacklist_file.truncate()
```

You open the file in read+write mode, load the JSON content, append the *user_id* you mentioned and then overwrite the file with the updated JSON content.